# How to update table using correlated query in postgresql..?

Tags: postgresql

How to update using correlated query I am using postgresql?

Here is my example

```
CREATE TABLE t("no" integer,"name" character varying)
CREATE TABLE t1(no1 integer,name1 character varying)

INSERT INTO t("no", "name")VALUES (1, 'A');
INSERT INTO t("no", "name")VALUES (2, 'B');
INSERT INTO t("no", "name")VALUES (3, 'C');
INSERT INTO t("no", "name")VALUES (4, 'D');

INSERT INTO t1("no1", "name1")VALUES (1, 'Z');
INSERT INTO t1("no1", "name1")VALUES (2, 'Y');
INSERT INTO t1("no1", "name1")VALUES (3, 'X');
INSERT INTO t1("no1", "name1")VALUES (4, 'W');

select * from t
```

Output:

```
 - no    name
 - 1     A
 - 2     B
 - 3     C
 - 4     D

select * from t1
```

Output:

```
 - no1   name1
 - 1     Z
 - 2     Y
 - 3     X
 - 4     W

update t  
set name = T1.name 
from (select no1,name1 from t1) T1 
where t.no = T1.no1

select * from t
```

Output:

```
 - no       name
 - 1       (1,Z)
 - 2       (2,Y)
 - 3       (3,X)
 - 4       (4,W)
```

but I am expecting  answer like this

```
 - no       name
 - 1         Z
 - 2         Y
 - 3         X
 - 4         4
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
UPDATE t
SET "name" = t1.name1
FROM t1
WHERE t.no = T1.no1
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9df85/1)</kbd>

Comment: did you got the reason y column in t get updated by select columns in from
i mean 

update t  
set name = T1.name 
from (select no1,name1 from t1) T1 
where t.no = T1.no1

after executing this update query name is having values from this "from (select no1,name1 from t1)" not T1.name

Comment: Not sure about that. Your query wouldn't run because T1 had  no name column it was name1. If you had that, it should work like mine. see here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8d2c0/1